# What is a good upgrade for Wacom Bamboo Fun

Tags: hardware-recommendation, drawing-tablet

At the moment, my girlfriend is using her old [Wacom Bamboo Fun](http://www.amazon.de/Wacom-Bamboo-Fun-Medium-Grafik-Tablett/dp/B000W0BB3I).

Because x-mas is near I am thinking about buying her a new and/or better device!
The price should be between 200€ and 300€.

While researching on Google I found the 2 following devices:

- Wacom CTH-680S-DEIT, Size M
- Wacom CTH-680S-S, Size M

What do you guys think?

Answer (score 2):

The "Bamboo Fun" was Wacom's bare-bones, entry-level, dirt-cheap, option. It was the least robust of any tablet. Wacom appears to have discontinued that model or anything like it.

The CTH-680S series **are Bamboo** tablets. Just not the "Fun" model. They are more in line with the standard "Bamboo" and the "Bamboo Create" tablets. They are *slightly* better than the Bamboo Fun was, but not a great deal better. They merely renamed the "Bamboo" line to "Intuos" and the CTH-680S series appears to be specifically non-American. Not sure why they use the number/letter model rather than the "Intuos" name.

[This is the CTH-680S-DEIT](http://www.wacom.com/en/us/creative/intuos-s) (Intuos Pen & Tablet) and [This is the CTH-680S-S](http://www.wacom.com/en/us/creative/intuos-manga) (Intuos Manga)

These are still entry level tablets - and, in fact, they *are* the Bamboo tablets. You will gain a bit of pressure sensitivity and features with these tablets, but you won't gain a great deal. Technically, yes, these would be upgrades from the "Bamboo Fun" but not drastic upgrades.

The next logical step up from these is the [Intuos Pro](http://www.wacom.com/en/us/creative/intuos-pro-m).

Other than the dramatic price difference, the Intuos Pro offers double the pressure sensitivity, higher LPI resolution, side buttons on the stylus, expression buttons on the tablet, ergonomics (tilt, rotation, etc) and many more features.

Then the next step above the Intuos Pro would be a [Cintiq](http://www.wacom.com/en/us/creative/cintiq-22-hd). The Cintiq is basically an intuos Pro built into a monitor. You connect it to a system just like you would connect a monitor, then draw on the screen with the stylus.

Comment: So what you say is, that my girlfriends actual old, white Bamboo Fun (that i linked in my question) is THE SAME device as, for example, the CTH-680S-DEIT ???

Comment: Basically, yes. The "Bamboo" tablets were simply renamed to "Intuos" and it appears that outside the US, CTH-680S is used rather than "Intuos". Perhaps not the *exact same* as the Bamboo Fun, but very, very close to it. They moved buttons and changed colors, but the tech is the same.

Comment: Are you really sure, that the tech is the same?
The "old" Bamboo has 512 Pressure Levels, for example.
The "new" Bamboo/Intuos has 1024!

Comment: Ahh yes. The "fun" was even more entry level. So you are correct, the CTH-680S will be a little better than a "Bamboo Fun". However, if you are seeking *more* out of a tablet, I'd forego the lower end tablets and just get an Intuos Pro.

Comment: I think i need to find out, which kind of upgrades/features my girlfriend needs/wants. she uses her actual Bamboo 1-2 times a week. and she's doing the drawing-stuff just as a hobby.
so, if she wants to do more professional drawings, i will go for the intuos pro. otherwise i will take the CTH-680S (maybe i will add the wireless-kit, too)

Comment: I've edited my answer to reflect the very specific low-end "Fun" model which I missed before.

Answer (score 1):

My opinion is that all three of those tablets you're looking at are all entry level tablets so I wouldn't personally look into getting another entry.  If you use it regularly like some do by replacing the mouse with your tablet and you love to draw I would look into saving more and getting a

[Cintiq](http://www.amazon.de/Wacom-Interactive-Display-LCD-Display-Sprachversion/dp/B00BXTMC30/ref=sr_1_1?s=computers&ie=UTF8&qid=1412686775&sr=1-1&keywords=cintiq):

[image]

but since your question requested within a price I do believe that you would enjoy the Wacom Intuos Pro which I think is your Wacom CTH-680S-DEIT.  This question is somewhat subjective though and answers would be based on ones preference, but if all else fails I would simply just ask your girlfriend what she wants and if she wants to advance from an entry level tablet.  I say that because I occasionally use my tablet when I have time to just relax and draw but that doesn't mean I want to upgrade from my [Intuos5](http://www.bestbuy.com/site/wacom-intuos5-small-tablet-and-pen-black/1308136484.p;jsessionid=B36AECBB48FEB379CB948CA1DC5A0D22.bbolsp-app01-182?id=mp1308136484&skuId=1308136484&st=wacom%20tablet&cp=1&lp=12#tab=buyingOptions).

Comment: Can you tell me the difference between the "Intuos Pro M" and the "CTH-680S-DEIT Intuos, Size M" ?